# What is the best way to return multiple values from django views.py to a template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

What would be the best way of returning multiple values in a Django views.py to the template?

For example, I want people to access any user's public profile by entering their username in the URL:

**views.py**

```
def public_profile(request, username_in_url):
    #Get appropriate user data from database
    user = User.objects.get(username = username_in_url)
    username = user.username
    first_name = user.first_name
    last_name = user.last_name
    date_joined = user.date_joined
    bio = user.userprofile.bio
    matchday_rating = user.userprofile.matchday_rating
    following = user.userprofile.following
    followers = user.userprofile.followers
    ..
    ..
    [return render_to_response..?]
    [use a Class instead and store values in a context?]
```

**public_profile.html**

```
   <h2> {{username}} </h2><br><br>

   <h4> 
       First Name: {{first_name}} <br>
       Last Name: {{last_name}} <br>
       Date Joined: {{date_joined}} <br><br>
       Matchday Rating: {{matchday_rating}} <br>
       Following: {{following}} <br>
       Followers: {{followers}}
   </h4>

   <br>

   <h4> User Bio: </h4><br>
   <p>{{bio}}</p>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<username>\s)/$', 'fantasymatchday_1.views.register_success'),
```

Comment: There's no need to create another class when you already have a class you can pass: the User.

Comment: @DanielRoseman good point, I am also unsure of my URL pattern as it does not seem to recognise the string as a parameter. Could you offer any help on this? :)

Comment: You should have asked a new question. However it is completely broken: `\s` matches only a single space. You probably want `\w+` for multiple alphanumeric characters, or `[\w-_]+` if you also want dashes and underscores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the user fields in a dictionary and pass it as context to `render_to_response`:

```
def public_profile(request, username_in_url):
    user = User.objects.get(username = username_in_url)
    context = {
        'first_name': user.first_name,
        # ...
    }
    return render_to_response('public_profile.html', context)
```

It may be simpler to just pass the user object to the template:

```
def public_profile(request, username_in_url):
    user = User.objects.get(username = username_in_url)
    context = {
        'user': user,
    }
    return render_to_response('public_profile.html', context)
```

The  template would then need to reference the fields of `user`:

```
First Name: {{user.first_name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your url matching pattern is not right:

Try this:

urls.py

```
(r'^(?P<username_in_url>\w+)$', 'fantasymatchday_1.views.register_success')
```

I'm also not sure that you are pointing to your view the right way (register_success is the function you call in urls.py but in your example above you call the function public_profile).

Comment: support for `\s` is not appropriate， `[\w-_]+` will be better